# Limits, $\inf$ and $\sup$ of sets in a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: limits, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I was scrolling through a textbook on probability theory (using measure theory) and one of the excercises states:

---

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and $(A_n)_{n\geq1}$ a sequence of events in $\mathcal{A}$. Show that
$$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\inf} \;A_n\in\mathcal{A}, \quad  \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup} \;A_n\in\mathcal{A},\quad\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\inf} \;A_n \subset \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup} \;A_n$$

---

What does it mean for a sequence of events (the subsets $A$ of the  $\mathcal{A}$ $\sigma$-algebra) to take its limit (as $n$ approaches infinity), inf and sup?

I am not looking for a proof of the statements in question (even though a link to a source would be interesting as well).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172167/interpretation-of-limsup-liminf-of-sets

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107931/215011

Comment: It turns out $\liminf A_n = \{ x \mid x \in A_n \text{ for all but finitely many $n$} \}$ and $\limsup A_n = \{ x \mid x \in A_n \text{ for infinitely many $n$} \}$. You can read more about why this is true at an old blog post of mine [here](https://grossack.site/2020/11/08/quick-analysis-trick-3.html)