# Example of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I am new to probability and I'm trying to understand the concept of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of events through an example. I am very comfortable with the technical definitions given by set operations and the interpretations that the $\limsup$ of a sequence of events is the event whose outcomes occur infinitely often in the sequence and the $\liminf$ is the event whose outcomes always occur after some finite time. All of this is well explained in other questions (such as this one: [Intuitive interpretation of limsup and liminf of sequences of sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172167/intuitive-interpretation-of-limsup-and-liminf-of-sequences-of-sets)).

What I would like to do is better understand this concept through an example. The simplest one I can think of is to consider a fair 6-sided die. At time $n$ we roll it and record the outcome, this is a single event $A_n$. Thus we have a sequence of events $\{A_n\}$ and I would like to determine its $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

I think both the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ in this example should be $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ since all will occur infinitely often and will always occur. Is this right?

Other examples are also welcomed as I'm having trouble coming up with one where $\liminf \neq \limsup$.

Comment: $A_n$ is a random variable and $\{A_n\}$ is a set containing a random variable, not an event. $\{A_9 = 4\}$ would be an example of notation conventionally used to denote an event

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes I think you're right and maybe this is why I am confused. So the sequence $\{A_n\}$ is an outcome that has already been realized. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know what that sequence is - it's legitimate to talk about limsup of a sequence of (real valued) random variables but it's not the same thing as limsup of a sequence of sets (e.g. events, which are subsets of the sample space)

Comment: @MatthewTowers Maybe it's better if I first look at an example of a sequence of events.

Comment: OK, but you haven't defined any sequences of events. Any event in your example is a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. $A_n$ isn't an event, it's a random variable.

Comment: @MatthewTowers So if we were to carry out the experiment and got the sequence $\{1, 2, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, \ldots\}$ would this be an event or instead a sequence of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets roll the fair dice infinitely many times. The probability that 6 will appear infinitely many times is 1 (The example sequence: 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 6,...), while the probability of it appearing every single time from some point in time to infinity is 0 (The example sequence: 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,...). You may also take a look at Borel-Canteli theorems.

Comment: Thank you, I think this solves most of my confusion! So the $\liminf$ is the empty set but how would we write the $\limsup$? I think it should be something like $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, but wouldn't this correspond to the event where we get $1-6$? So maybe the $\limsup$ should be $\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{5\}, \{6\}\}$?

Comment: Actually, you need to think in terms of entire sequences here.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.