# lim sup of set, elementary set theory

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I am referring to the post:
[lim sup and lim inf of sequence of sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107931/lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-sequence-of-sets/993208?noredirect=1#comment2031930_993208)

how would we prove that for $\limsup A_n $ $x$ is in infinitely many sets $A_i$?

If I define set $A$ as a set that consists of infinitely many sets $x \in $ $A_i$, what is its complement $A^C$ ?

Namely, I would like to prove that

$$
 A^c \subseteq \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\ge N} A_n^C
$$

Answer (score 0):

In the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107938/75923) to the post you mention it is explained *very nicely* that $$x\in\limsup A_n=
\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n\iff x\text{ is contained in }A_n\text{ for infinitely many }n\in\mathbb N$$

So I don't really understand why you are asking this question here.

$x\in(\limsup A_n)^c$ then tells us that $x$ is contained in $A_n$ for a **finite** number of $n\in\mathbb N$ or equivalently that some $N$ exists with $n\ge N\Rightarrow x\in A_n^c$

That means $x\in\liminf A_n^c=\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\ge N} A_n^c$ wich is also  nicely explained in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107938/75923).

Comment: #drhab are you sure that $x\notin\limsup A_n$ tells us that $x$ is contained in a **finite** number of $A_i$ or equivalently that some $N$ exists with $n\ge N\Rightarrow x\in A_n^c$ ?

Complement of infinitely many is not always finite, or am I wrong?

Comment: $\{n\in\mathbb N|x\in A_n\}$ not infinite $\iff$ $\{n\in\mathbb N|x\in A_n\}$ finite $\iff\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq N\left[x\in A_n^{c}\right]$

Comment: I have another stupid question. Can at the same time hold: $x \in A_n^c$ and $x \in A_n $ ?

Comment: Are in the $A_n^C $ included all the other sets from the sequence?

Comment: $x\in A_n^c$ can be interpreted as $x\notin A_n$ wich cannot hold at the same time as $x\in A_n$. I do not understand the question in your last comment.