# Negation of a mathematical statement containing the word: but finitely many

Tags: logic

I have a mathematical statement of the form:

**Case**: Fix $ε>0$ and three distinct elements $b₁,b₂,b₃$ in a set $A$. Then all but finitely many $q∈A$ satisfy:
$$(1-ε)a_{q}<c_{q}$$

where $a_{q}$ and $c_{q}$ are real sequences.

Then my question is to find the negation of this case.

Comment: Begin by stating precisely what "all but finitely many" means.

Comment: ["all but finitely many"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310266/what-does-for-all-but-finitely-many-n-in-the-definition-of-limit-inferior-me)

Comment: If you copy and paste here, please at least check the text that you pasted. You're missing a "fi" ligature in the title.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Yes, I understood that it means that the statement is true in all cases, except that there might be some finite number of exceptions.

Comment: The negation of "all but finitely many" will be "finitely many".