# What does "ordering of sets by inclusion" mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was recently introduced to partial order relations. Although I understand the concept of a relation, I do not understand how subsets can have a sequence, or what that has to do with the phrase "ordering of sets by inclusion." Can anyone help me clarify the concept with an intuitive example?

Comment: It means containment. Llike, $A <B$ if $A \subset B$

Comment: @Bhaskar Vashishth: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Can you provide a quote of where this phrase appears?  I'm not sure what you mean by "ordering of sequence of subset".

Comment: The story is long @augurar; I'm also confused whether to include the word 'sequence'. So, I gave ??

Answer (score 7):

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of sets.  Then for sets $S_1, S_2 \in \mathcal{S}$, we can define $S_1 \prec S_2$ to mean $S_1 \subset S_2$.

So for example, considering sets of integers, we can say $\{1, 2, 3\} \prec \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  This is a partial order because not all sets are comparable.  For instance $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{1, 3, 5\}$ are not comparable because neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: Thanks, sir. +1 for this. At the first sight, it nailed the doubt.

Comment: Sir, one question; by ordering what do we get? The definition of set  in naive set theory is that it is an **unordered** collection of mathematical objects. So,  what does this "ordering' all mean?

Comment: @user36790 It's a way of giving the set additional structure.  A set along with a partial order is called a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).  We can then study the properties of this new object.

Comment: A set along with a partial order means? Suppose $\{a,b,c,d\}$ where $a < b< c$. Then the set along with partial order relation is meaning $\{(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)\}$ this? I am new, so I face problems with these phrases like **set along with a relation**:|

Comment: @user36790 It just means we think about the set and the relation together as a single mathematical object.  In your comment you provide a set $S$ and a relation $R$ on the set.  If we consider these together, we can think of the pair as representing a partially ordered set.

Comment: Then you are saying $\{\{a,b,c,d\}, R\}$ is the partial order set? Elsewhere, I saw $(\{a,b.c,d\} R)$ as termed as loop-digraph. Is it different from the above?

Comment: @user36790 A set and a relation can also be used to represent a digraph, it all depends on the interpretation you attach to it.  If the relation is a partial order, then the corresponding digraph has no directed cycles.

Comment: So, a poset is the power set basically & not every element of the power set can be related by partial order, right? Then how can I use this to define the supremum & infimum of a set, can you tell? BTW, can you tell me what **directed cycles** mean?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a set $\mathtt{S}$.  Now denote power set of $\mathtt{S}$ by $\mathcal{P}(\mathtt{S})$. Then $\mathcal{P}(\mathtt{S})$ is a poset under the relation $\subseteq$ (inclusion).

1. **Reflexive**- As $A \subseteq A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathtt{S})$
2. **AntiSymmetric**- As $A\subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$  $\implies A=B$
3. **Transitive**- You can see it now, I am sure.

So it is a partial order on $\mathcal{P}(\mathtt{S})$.

On any set of sets, inclusion is a partial order.

Comment: If set $S$ has less than 3 elements (or even less than 2 elements), can we infer that inclusion is a partial order?

Answer (score 1):

Given any family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ there is a poset $P=(\mathcal{F},\{(A,B)\in\mathcal{F}^2:A\subseteq B\})$ corresponding to that family ordered by inclusion. Now by an "inclusion maximal/maximum/minimal/minimum" set in $\mathcal{F}$ what is meant is simply a maximal/maximim/minimal/minimum element of $\mathcal{F}$. Also its worth noting that every partial order is isomorphic to a family of sets ordered by inclusion, in particular the principal lower sets of any partial order when ordered by set inclusion are always isomorphic to said partial order.