# Application of Fatou's Lemma but something simpler is better?

Tags: measure-theory

**The question**

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $A_n$ be a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{A}$.

Define $A := \{ x \in X $ such that  for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $x ∈ A_n$ $ \}$

Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \mu (A_n) \geq \mu(A)$

**My attempt**

$ \mu (A_n) = \int_X \chi_{A_n} d\mu$ and so by Fatou's lemma:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \mu (A_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \int_X \chi_{ A_n} \geq \int_X \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \chi_{A_n} d\mu$

Now all I need to show is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \chi_{A_n}(x)  = \chi_A(x)$ a.e

Consider $x\in A$ then eventually $x\in A_n \forall n $ eventually and so $\chi_{A_n}(x) = 1 \forall n $ and so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \chi_{A_n}(x)  = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1= \chi_A(x)$

Now consider $x\not\in A$ then $\forall N \in \mathbb{N} \exists n >N$ such that $x \not\in A_n$
and so $\inf_{m \geq n} \chi_{A_n}(x) = 0 \forall n$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \chi_{A_n}(x)  = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0= \chi_A(x)$

Ando so the required follows.

However this feels awfully complicated and I was wondering if anyone has any tips for something simpler

Comment: Have you made the observation that $$A=\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} A_{n}=\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_{j}$$ holds? This observation makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatou's lemma and measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141697/fatous-lemma-and-measurable-sets)

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much the union intersection representation was very helpful! I  think your notation might be off unfortunately as the $A_n$ are subsets of the real line and thus lim inf's are not defined onto them (to the best of my knowledge :) )

Comment: The liminf and liminf can also be defined for subsets. In my previous comment, the intersection and union is its definition. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341089/show-that-lim-inf-a-n-subset-lim-sup-n-a-n.