# Express the set of all paths with infinite $1$'s using set theoretical representation and elements of another set

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, random-walk

Define the collection $\mathscr{A}$ of subsets of $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\infty}$ as
$$\mathscr{A}=\{S\times\Omega:S\subseteq\{0,1\}^{l},l\ge1\}$$
Let all infinite length paths be denoted by
$$\omega=(\omega_n)_{n\ge1}$$
Then, define $A$, the set of all paths with infinitely many up($\{1\}$) moves by
$$A=\left\{\omega:\sum\mathbb{I}_{\{\omega_n=1\}}=\infty\right\}$$

> Express $A$ using sets of $\mathscr{A}$ and 'countably many', $\cup$, 'complementation', $\cap$... (set theoretic representation)

My approach:
Initially, I proceeded by defining $A_1,A_2...\in\mathscr{A}$ as $A_k=S_k\times\Omega$, where $S_k=\{1,1,...$ $_k$ $_{times}$$\}$ and using $\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\bigcap}}A_k=\{1,1,1...\}$.
But, this excludes the cases the paths with finite $0$'s.
However, if I take $\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\bigcup}}A_k=\{1,1,1...\}$, this also includes paths that do not satisfy the infinte $1$'s condition.
How must I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_k:=\left\{\left(\omega_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}\in \Omega\mid \omega_k=1\right\}$. Then the equality 
$$
A=\bigcap_{j\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{k\geqslant j}A_k
$$
holds (see [this thread for a better understanding of the limit superior and inferior of a sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107931/lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-sequence-of-sets)). In order to see that $A_k$ belongs to $\mathcal A$, write this as $S_k\times\Omega$ where $S_k:=\left\{\left(\omega_i\right)_{i=1}^k\in \{0,1\}^k\mid \omega_k=1\right\}$.

Comment: do you mean $A_k$ in $\mathcal{A}$ or $A_k$ in $\mathscr{A}$. The  proof makes sense, if t's the latter.

Comment: I mean that $A_k\in\mathcal A$.

Comment: I think it should be $\underset{j\ge 1}{\bigcap}\underset{k\ge j}{\bigcup}{A_k}$ and not $A_j$.

Comment: Also, could you please explain the construction of that set a little. I am a little lost.

Comment: @ZaIra I edited in order to include a link and correcting the typo.