# Why is the Cantor set not defined by a limit?

Tags: cantor-set

The Cantor set, as showed in books and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set), is defined in terms of $C_k$, the finite Cantor set of level $k$:

$$ \mathcal{C} = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty C_k $$

But after intersection only the "last" remains, so, why not to define it by a limit?

$$\mathcal{C} = \lim_{k \to \infty} C_k$$

It is perhaps a naive intuition, but I not see a good justification.

---

(adding here a note after first answer, only for comment the comments)

NOTE: if it is not only a  question of choice of notation, but also about context and semantics. 
Can I tell an engineer that *the intersection* is a kind of specification, something like a project to explain "what I need", and *the limit* is a "what  I get", the end result?    ...Or perhaps the inverse, as suggested by @HansLundmark (thanks the comment! also thnaks @SangchulLee!). I am supposing that $C_k$ is a "decreasing sequence",  $C_1 \supseteq C_2 \supseteq C_3 \supseteq \dotsb$, 
so using [your anser](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1912079/70274) we can say 
  "it's natural to define the limit as the intersection: $C_n \to \mathcal{C}$ as $n\to\infty$", 
  where $\mathcal{C}$ is defined by intersection.

About comment of @LordShark: its is possible to use  "limits" notation in the context of set sequences without "develop a theory" for it?  @HansLundmark's link is a satisfactory answer for it?

Comment: Why develop a theory of "limits" of sets to define $\cal C$ when it's simply an intersection?

Comment: The intersection *is* the limit in this case (when you have a decreasing sequence of sets). See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107931/lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-sequence-of-sets/1912079#1912079

Comment: Of course we can perfectly make sense of $\mathcal{C} = \lim_{k\to\infty} C_k$. On the other hand, we need some works to put that notion to a rigorous mathematical framework. And that is sort of asking too much for this very specific case, as pointed out by others.

Comment: Hi @SangchulLee, I edited a note, can you check if it is ok?

Comment: The notion of limit explained in HansLundmark's answer is sufficient for this case, which is an instance of limit notion in lattice theory. It definitely works for your sequence. Since $\mathcal{C}$ can be realized as a bona-fide limit, you can interpret $\mathcal{C}$ as the *ideal target* and $C_n$ as approximations of $\mathcal{C}$ whose accuracy improves progressively in $n$, just as for limits in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, the intersection is the limit. There is no final set, and we don't want to appeal to any concept of convergence of sets or categorical limits when this is usually introduced in an undergraduate course because this would not be understood by the students. But you're allowed to take arbitrary intersections, and this is an elementary way to get the limit of a nested decreasing sequence of sets.

Comment: Can I tell an engineer that *the intersection* is a specification, something like a project to explain "what I need", and *the limit* is a "what  I get", the end result?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: No, that is totally wrong.  The intersection is equal to the limit (in the sense as discussed in the comments), and they are both the end result.