# Let $\{E_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets in X. Show that $A\in\mathfrak{M}$, where $A$ is the set of all x that lie in infinitely many $E_k$'s.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The problem arises from Walter Rudin's *Real & Complex Analysis*:
[image]

The highlighted texts, however, would NOT make any sense if $A$ is not measurable. All my attempts to show that $A\in\mathfrak{M}$ have failed; any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: write $A$ with the $(E_k)$. Hint: an infinite set of $\mathbb N$ is not bounded

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107931/lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-sequence-of-sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A =\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n\ge N} E_k
$$

By definition, this means any point of $A$ belongs to infinitely many of $E_k$. By the fact that $E_k$ are all measurable, you conclude $A$ is as well.