# How to understand $\lim\sup\ A_n$?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $A_n$ be sequence of events, My book has the following:

$$P(\lim\sup\ A_n) = P(A_n\ {\rm occurs\ for\ infinity\ many\ } n)$$

Why is this equality correct?

I know that: $\lim\sup\ A_n$, is equal to (not formal): All results that belong to infinite events in the sequence $A_n$.

How is this the same as: $A_n$ occurs for infinity many $n$? and what's the meaning of this at all? maybe it's a translation problem (although my professor is native speaker)...

Comment: It means: $$x\in\limsup A_n\iff x\in\bigcap_{n\in I}A_n$$for some infinite set $I\subset\Bbb N.$ I cannot tell you why it is the same as " All results that belong to infinite events in the sequence $A_n$" because that sentence is less clear to me than the one you ask for explanation.

Comment: @AnneBauval but I'm asking for explanation for: "All results that belong to infinite events in the sequence "

Comment: @coudy sorry it doesn't

Comment: zoro No, you asked for an explanation of "$A_n$ occurs for infinity many $n$", which is a usual formulation and which I translated formally. Not for an explanation of your own formulation, "" All results that belong to infinite events in the sequence $A_n$
", which I find unclear.

Comment: Maybe also useful (since events are just sets in the sample space): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107931/lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-sequence-of-sets

Answer (score 1):

Your professor's formulation means:
$$x\in\limsup A_n\iff\exists I\text{ infinite }\subset\Bbb N,\quad x\in\bigcap_{n\in I}A_n.$$
This equivalence is correct because:

- the classical definition is
  $$\limsup A_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k;$$
- $$x\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k\iff$$
  $$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad\exists k\ge n\quad x\in A_k\iff$$
  $$\{k\in\Bbb N\mid x\in A_k\}\text{ is unbounded;}$$
- a subset of $\Bbb N$ is unbounded iff it is infinite.

I cannot tell you why it is "the same as" *your own* formulation (*"All results that belong to infinite events in the sequence $A_n$"*) because that one is less clear to me than the usual sentence *"$A_n$ occurs for infinity many $n$"* for which you asked for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $\limsup A_n$ for a sequence of sets $\{ A_n \}$ is
$$
  \limsup A_n = \bigcap _{n = 1} ^\infty \bigcup _{m \geq n} A_m.  
$$

Under this formulation, it is clear that $x \in \limsup A_n$ if and only if for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a positive number $m \geq n$ which $x \in A_m$. Inuitively speaking, if we now pick $m = n$ assuming they are fixed in the last step, then there is $m_2 \geq m + 1$ which $x \in A_{m_2}$. This tells you that $x$ must be in infinitely many $A_m$, since this process can be continued indefinitely.

On the other hand, if $x$ is not in $\limsup A_n$, then by De Morgan's law
$$
  x \in (\limsup A_n)^c 
= \bigcup _{n = 1} ^\infty \bigcap _{m \geq n} A_m^c.  
$$
This is the set which there is $n$, which $x$ is not in $A_m$ for all $m \geq n$, meaning $x$ stops belonging to $A_n$ after a finite number of them. This shows that if $x \not \in \limsup A_n$ then $x$ is not in infinitely many $A_n$'s.

I think this problem arises mainly because the book does not bring up the set formulation of $\limsup A_n$, and simply define $\limsup A_n$ as the set which $x$ belongs to infinitely many $A_n$'s.